# Markup of this code is invalid?

Tags: html, markup

End tag td seen, but there were open elements. I don't get it, what's wrong with this markup?

```
<td class="column-9">
  <img src="http://4onlinecasinos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/the-best-online-casinos-yes-transparent-good-e1395756650738.png" alt="This images tells that the option is positive" width="40" height="40" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-61" />
</td>
<td class="column-10">
  <a href="http://4onlinecasinos.com/out/online-casinos-888casino" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://4onlinecasinos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/the-best-online-casinos-visit-button.png" alt="Visit this Online Casino" width="54" height="54" class="img-visit" />
  </td>
  <td class="column-11">
    <a href="http://4onlinecasinos.com/out/online-casinos-888casino" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://4onlinecasinos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/the-best-online-casinos-info-sign-e1396351202753.png" alt="This gives you more specific information about the online casino offer" width="40" height="40" class="img-info" />
    </td>
```

Comment: Your anchors tags has no closing tag

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo a simple HTML bug

Answer (score 6):

```
<td class="column-10">
```

Inside a TD

```
<a href="http://4onlinecasinos.com/out/online-casinos-888casino" target="_blank">
```

Inside an A inside a TD

```
<img src="http://4onlinecasinos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/the-best-online-casinos-visit-button.png" alt="Visit this Online Casino" width="54" height="54" class="img-visit" />
```

An IMG. The element is self closing. Still inside an A inside a TD

```
</td>
```

Trying to close a TD but currently inside an A

You can't close the TD before you close the A, you are missing `</a>`.

Answer (score 4):

you need to close your link `<a>` tag

```
<td class="column-9">
  <img src="http://4onlinecasinos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/the-best-online-casinos-yes-transparent-good-e1395756650738.png" alt="This images tells that the option is positive" width="40" height="40" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-61" /></a>
</td>
<td class="column-10">
  <a href="http://4onlinecasinos.com/out/online-casinos-888casino" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://4onlinecasinos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/the-best-online-casinos-visit-button.png" alt="Visit this Online Casino" width="54" height="54" class="img-visit" /></a>
  </td>
  <td class="column-11">
    <a href="http://4onlinecasinos.com/out/online-casinos-888casino" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://4onlinecasinos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/the-best-online-casinos-info-sign-e1396351202753.png" alt="This gives you more specific information about the online casino offer" width="40" height="40" class="img-info" /></a>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that is missing there is the `</a>`. And it would be making the HTML markup invalid.

It is totally invalid, you should enclose the elements as your open them.

Here is the markup that you can trust on:

```
<td class="column-9">
  <img src="http://4onlinecasinos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/the-best-online-casinos-yes-transparent-good-e1395756650738.png" alt="This images tells that the option is positive" width="40" height="40" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-61" />
</td>
<td class="column-10">
  <a href="http://4onlinecasinos.com/out/online-casinos-888casino" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://4onlinecasinos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/the-best-online-casinos-visit-button.png" alt="Visit this Online Casino" width="54" height="54" class="img-visit" />
</a>
  </td>
  <td class="column-11">
    <a href="http://4onlinecasinos.com/out/online-casinos-888casino" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://4onlinecasinos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/the-best-online-casinos-info-sign-e1396351202753.png" alt="This gives you more specific information about the online casino offer" width="40" height="40" class="img-info" />
   </a>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Close `<a>`:

```
<a href="http://4onlinecasinos.com/out/online-casinos-888casino" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://4onlinecasinos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/the-best-online-casinos-visit-button.png" alt="Visit this Online Casino" width="54" height="54" class="img-visit" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this @ http://topgambler.nl/gratis-geld/
Now it works for me. great job!